# fill in new dataframe column according to array condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([['a', 0, 1.2,12.5,3], ['a',1, 4,5.,6.885],
                ['a', 2, 2.3,3.133,4.3], ['a', 3, 5.678,6.,7.34556],
                ['a', 4, 6.5,7,8.1344], ['b',0, 10.7,11.4,12.1332],
                ['b',1, 14.,15,16.0155], ['b',2, 17.3,18.,9.11],
                ['b', 3, 22.2, 33.233, 1.2323], 
                ['c', 0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3], 
                ['c', 1, 2.2, 3.43, 54.5],
                ['d', 0 , 2.2, 2.2, 3.],
                ['d',1, 3.4, 4., 5.6],
                ['d', 2, 3.3, 4, 5.]])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['name', 'id', 'x', 'y', 'z'])

df['id'] = pd.to_numeric(df['id'])
df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(df['x'])
df['y'] = pd.to_numeric(df['y'])
df['z'] = pd.to_numeric(df['z'])

df
    name    id  x       y       z
0   a       0   1.2     12.5    3
1   a       1   4       5.0     6.885
2   a       2   2.3     3.133   4.3
3   a       3   5.678   6.0     7.34556
4   a       4   6.5     7       8.1344
5   b       0   10.7    11.4    12.1332
6   b       1   14.0    15      16.0155
7   b       2   17.3    18.0    9.11
8   b       3   22.2    33.233  1.2323
9   c       0   1.1     2.2     3.3
10  c       1   2.2     3.43    54.5
11  d       0   2.2     2.2     3.0
12  d       1   3.4     4.0     5.6
13  d       2   3.3     4       5.0
```

And I have an array with the same size:

```
the_array = np.array([['a', 82.365],
                      ['a', 82.365],
                      ['a', 82.365],
                      ['a', 82.365],
                      ['b', 136.879],
                      ['b', 136.879],
                      ['b', 136.879],
                      ['b', 136.879],
                      [None, None],
                      [None, None],
                      [None, None],
                      [None, None],
                      [None, None],
                      [None, None]], dtype=object)
```

Now, I want to create a new column in df, in which I will fill the values of `thearray` according to column `name`.

I want at every row in df where the name is the same as the name in `thearray` to have the same value (as in `thearray`).

**Result I want:**

```
    name    id  x         y       z         new_col
0   a       0   1.200   12.500  3.00000     82.365
1   a       1   4.000   5.000   6.88500     82.365
2   a       2   2.300   3.133   4.30000     82.365
3   a       3   5.678   6.000   7.34556     82.365
4   a       4   6.500   7.000   8.13440     82.365
5   b       0   10.700  11.400  12.13320    136.879
6   b       1   14.000  15.000  16.01550    136.879
7   b       2   17.300  18.000  9.11000     136.879
8   b       3   22.200  33.233  1.23230     136.879
9   c       0   1.100   2.200   3.30000     None
10  c       1   2.200   3.430   54.50000    None
11  d       0   2.200   2.200   3.00000     None
12  d       1   3.400   4.000   5.60000     None
13  d       2   3.300   4.000   5.00000     None
```

I tried:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['name'] == the_array[:, 0], the_array[:, 1], the_array[:, 1])
```

but I received:

```
    name    id  x   y   z   new_col
0   a       0   1.200   12.500  3.00000     82.365
1   a       1   4.000   5.000   6.88500     82.365
2   a       2   2.300   3.133   4.30000     82.365
3   a       3   5.678   6.000   7.34556     82.365
4   a       4   6.500   7.000   8.13440     136.879
5   b       0   10.700  11.400  12.13320    136.879
6   b       1   14.000  15.000  16.01550    136.879
7   b       2   17.300  18.000  9.11000     136.879
8   b       3   22.200  33.233  1.23230     None
9   c       0   1.100   2.200   3.30000     None
10  c       1   2.200   3.430   54.50000    None
11  d       0   2.200   2.200   3.00000     None
12  d       1   3.400   4.000   5.60000     None
13  d       2   3.300   4.000   5.00000     None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with [`Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['new_col'] = df['name'].map({'a': 82.365, 'b': 136.879})
```

`the_array` has the same size as `df`, but it is not aligned. It seems to represent a map `name -> value` for a set of unique names. So it should be represented by a `dict` and not an `array`. It is easy to construct this `dict` with a dict-comprehension that iterates over the rows of the array:

```
the_map = {k: v for k, v in the_array if k}
df['new_col'] = df['name'].map(the_map)
```

Thinking about what your data means and how it is best represented is a good approach to write elegant code and to find solutions in such situations.